# boost::any number cast

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I put positive 'int' to my any variable. Then I am trying to cast it to 'unsigned long'. And I got an exception about bad any cast. How I can make the use of 'boost::any_cast' more flexible conserning integer data.

Comment: You can't.  `boost::any` is not very flexible in this regard.  The types have to match exactly.  If you have a known list of types, I'd suggest looking into `boost::variant` instead.

Comment: By the way, boost::any is horribly inefficient for holding integers. Each any entry uses a pointer in addition to the value itself. You'd be better off just making an array of the largest integer type.

Answer (score 4):

Extract it into a temporary variable and then cast that to the integer type that you want.

Comment: Problem that where I apply boost::any_cast, I don't know what type it was the former type.

Comment: @user14416: You can't use boost::any that way. You must know the type, or at least work your way through a list of the possible types.